# Disable Form Completion in MS Edge

Tags: javascript, html, forms, angular, microsoft-edge

I am trying to find a way to disable the feature in Microsoft Edge, that keeps form values, specifically inputs, from retaining their value when a page refreshes. You can look at the first name last name example on this page https://www.tutorialspoint.com/html/html_forms.htm to see the behavior. On Edge, if you type in the input field and immediately refresh the page, you will find the values are still present after the page has reloaded completely. I have tried this with the option disabled in the Edge browser settings and I have also set autocomplete="off" but neither of these seems to have any effect. I am specifically trying to do this within Angular 2, but i've found that the behavior directly affects the HTML inside of the Edge browser.

Comment: Looks like this behavior might be "by design" https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-edge/platform/issues/9847360/

Answer (score 0):

This is a poor answer but here is a quote from an MS Edge developer from the link in the comment

> In IE11 and Edge, we made the decision to ignore autocomplete=off

From [here](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-edge/platform/issues/9847360/)

This was done, it seems:

> to provide increased user value.

My solution is to select the form field and clear it using javascript on a reload. E.g.:

```
document.querySelector("#theInput")
   .addEventListener("load", function (event) { event.target.value = "" } )
```