# autocomplete="off" not working on Edge version 87.0.664.60

Tags: autocomplete, microsoft-edge

`Autocomplete="off"` not working in Microsoft Edge latest version 87.0.664.60. The attribute is showing as being set, however, is not appearing to take effect. An example of this can be seen on
https://www.w3schools.com/howto/tryit.asp?filename=tryhow_html_autocomplete_off.

Once you add values and submit, refresh the screen and start to retype values. I am finding this to be an issue in my current project

Comment: Hi this seems to be a known issue on MS Edge. Multiple questions about the same subject exist on StackOverflow, here is an example: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42652094/disable-form-completion-in-ms-edge

Comment: Hey @hamzahik thank. I see that this was posted almost 4 years ago. I was wondering if  this is still the Microsoft approach since their move to Chromium?

Comment: I find that when you go to `edge://settings/addresses` and enable **Save and fill addresses** and delete the value in **Addresses**, then the `autocomplete` will work well on Edge: https://i.stack.imgur.com/AzlMn.png. If you disable **Save and fill addresses**, then autocomplete will not work. The behavior is not the same as on Chrome. You can provide your feedback on Edge using **Alt+Shift+I** about this issue.

Comment: @YuZhou thanks. I believe if the user disables or enables it in their settings, then the browser autocomplete will work as expected. However, I am hoping that when I apply the setting in the html form control that I can pre-set the autocomplete to off for my application input fields. I have raised this with Edge using the browsers feedback option, but I have not received any update.

Comment: As you can see from the [browser compatibilty table](https://caniuse.com/input-autocomplete-onoff), `autocomplete="off"` is not well supported by Edge Chromium. I think you can only waiting for the official response now as there's no other workaround about this issue.

Comment: I am so not happy to ask that... but are there any known hacky ways to achieve disabled autofill/autocomplete?

Answer (score 0):

I'm facing this issue as well on a Mac with Version 90.0.818.62 (Official build) (64-bit). I played around with https://www.w3schools.com/howto/tryit.asp?filename=tryhow_html_autocomplete_off and I guess I found a workaround.

With the default I get the auto suggest even at the first input field, see
[screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bjCHy.png).

While playing around with it I found out when I add another input field just behind for whatever weired reason the autocomplete doesn't appear for the input field where it was turned off, see [screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/USp8b.png). It can even be hidden. Form looks like this:

```html
<form action="/action_page.php">
  First name: <input type="text" name="fname" autocomplete="off"><input type="text" name="dummy" style="display:none"><br>
  Last name: <input type="text" name="lname" autocomplete="on"><br>
  <input type="submit">
</form>
```

Also the auto suggest for the second fields looks a little different, see [screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UYyS2.png). Maybe it's a different mode in Edge?!

Comment: This prevent autocompletition on the whole form