# Is there a way of disabling the autofill of input in React?

Tags: reactjs, materialize

I have a react app that has a couple of inputs. The problem is, whenever I navigate to the page, it auto-fills all the fields with previously entered data on Microsoft Edge (The new one). I use Materialize for my styling. I implement my form like so:

```
<form onSubmit={this.handleSubmit} autoComplete='off' className="login-form">
    <div className="input-field">
        <input 
        placeholder='Type email here' 
        id="email" 
        type="email"
        required 
        className="validate contact-input" 
        onChange={this.handleChange}/>
        
        <label 
        className="active" 
        htmlFor="email">Email</label>
    </div>

    <div className="input-field">
        <input 
        placeholder='Type password here' 
        id="password" 
        type="password"
        required 
        className="validate contact-input" 
        onChange={this.handleChange}/>

        <label 
        className="active" 
        htmlFor="password">Password</label>
    </div>

    <div className="input-field col s6">
        <button className="btn z-depth-2 login-btn">
            Sign In
        </button>
    </div>
</form>
```

Some solutions I have tried that do not work include:

```
<form autoComplete="off">
...
</form>

<form autoComplete="new-password">
...
</form>

<input autoComplete="off" />

<input autoComplete="new-password" />

<input autoComplete="none" />
```

Anyone know how to fix this?

Comment: Have you seen https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32785958/disable-input-text-suggestions-in-edge?

Comment: tried them. The one that came claose was the autoComplete="false" but it remains clear for just a few seconds then fills again

Comment: An old discussion says that it is simply ignored: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42652094/disable-form-completion-in-ms-edge and offers a workaround using javascript. There is also an interesting discussion in github: https://gist.github.com/runspired/b9fdf1fa74fc9fb4554418dea35718fe

Comment: For me, it works this [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73691203/13506884)

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
<input type="text" autocomplete="off" list="autocompleteOff" 
id="fieldId" name="fieldname" placeholder="Placeholder here" />
```

Answer from here : [Disable input text suggestions in Edge?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32785958/disable-input-text-suggestions-in-edge)

Comment: It still autofills on Edge